# Magento Order-number is not sequence

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, magento2.2.3

**Magento version: 2.2.3**

We have faced a strange issue in the sequence of order number for our site. For example this weekend Magento was at number 100034468 and the next order number that came in was 100034470. We don't know what happened to the order number 100034469.

Since this is the peak time for us, we are scarring that we may be missed the orders.

I have read some posts about the order number inconsistent on Magento StackExchange. Though, I have not satisfied with the answers. I want to have the clear reason for this issue. So, I'm posting this question.

Could you please help me to know why this has happened?

Looking for your quickest reply. Thanks.